# How to notify user of progress

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently planning a web based application, which needs to do long calculations on the server upon request. Now I would like to display a notification to the user, that the calculation is in progress, and then redirect that page as soon as the calculation is done.

There is no need to notify the user of the progress or display a progress bar, I simply want to exchange the site as soon as the calculation is done.

I am trying to stay clear of any additional webkits besides plain javascript, so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441935/how-to-create-server-side-progress-indicator-in-javascript) is much to complicated.

One idea I have is to just start a http query from javascript in the waiting page and not return anything on the server side until the calculation is done. This way I would keep the query blocked until the connection is finished. Once it is done, I return something and close the connection, so the blocked call can continue and redirect the user. However I am afraid that this might give me a timeout on the network if there is nothing going through that connection.

How is something like this normally handled?

Comment: How long does the calculation take? "long" is about as imprecise as it gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this is normally handled is doing periodic calls to a page that returns the progress. The simplest way it running an ajax call ever X seconds that returns 0 when not complete and 1 when complete.

Basically you should just poll the server for a status update on the job and do nothing until it returns 1

Answer (score 1):

I would go for ChrisR's solution.

And while the user is waiting for the process to complete, you can display a spinner (as Greg said) but I would go for a fancier solution rather than an animated gif :)

May I suggest to try the Heartcode CanvasLoader?

http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/

Good luck,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a spinner image?  http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=spinner